# How to setup a main controller in HMVC CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using HMVC in CodeIgniter https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home

How do I setup a controller that would automatically run when accessing a user-only page.
This is for the purpose of checking if a user is currently logged in or not. I've already made a helper to check if user is logged in:

```
<?php 
if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
if (!function_exists('is_logged_in')){
    function is_logged_in(){
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $logged_in = FALSE;
        $user_data = $CI->session->userdata('logged_in');
        if(!empty($user_data)){
            $logged_in = TRUE;
        }
        return $logged_in;
    }   
}
```

But the only thing that I know is to call this method on the constructor of each controller on each of the modules. I would be repeating the same code on every controller just to check if the user is logged in. Basically I want this function to be called everytime a user tries to access something inside the modules directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use _remap() for this. You can put this in MY_Controller if you are using one, for more information read the [Controller User Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html)

Here is something you can start with.

```
function _remap($method)
{
    if (method_exists($this, $method) && $this-my_custom_helper->is_logged_in())
    {
        $this->$method();
    }
    else
    {
        redirect('/auth/login/');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to extend the main controller class(CI_contorller I guess) and call this helper method in the that controller's constructor. Then extend all the other user related controller from this new controller.